# Correlated equilibrium proved by convexity (Games Theory)

Tags: game-theory, correlation, evolutionary-game-theory

I am finding very hard to understand how convexity works and why a correlated strategy if a convex linear combination of Nashes is a correlated equilibrium.
(Both concepts of Correlated strat. and correlated equilibrium are clear)

The following is the problem I can't grasp:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdMUj.png)

*Please feel free to modify my post I haven't been posting in a while and writing LateX feels very hard, also the question isn't well posed but I am trying to solve this on my own and this post is just another attempt to find a solution*

Thanks to anyone helping

Comment: Hi Adriano. Can you please provide the reference you're taking the exercise from, and some context (definitions and conventions) you use? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960